# import database in browser using phpmyadmin and xampp, there is an error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

i imported my sql file in phpmyadmin browser, but when i run it there is an error message like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3nNJ.png)

I have activated xampp, as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMAlh.png)
Can anyone provide a link or suggestion for my error